# Forum MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a sql query

I have this table (post_table):

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | topicId | userId |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 1       | kalle  |
| 2  | 1       | pelle  |
| 3  | 2       | laban  |
| 4  | 2       | kalle  |
| 5  | 2       | kalle  |
| 6  | 2       | kalle  |
| 7  | 1       | kalle  |
| 8  | 1       | kalle  |
| 9  | 2       | laban  |
| 10 | 1       | laban  |
| 11 | 2       | kalle  |
| 12 | 2       | kalle  |
| 13 | 3       | laban  |
| 14 | 1       | kalle  |
| 15 | 2       | kalle  |
| 16 | 1       | kalle  |
| 17 | 3       | laban  |
| 18 | 4       | laban  |
| 19 | 5       | laban  |
| 20 | 6       | pelle  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want to get only the rows where userId "kalle" have not read the post, they are

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | topicId | userId |
+----+---------+--------+
| 13 | 3       | laban  |
| 17 | 3       | laban  |
| 18 | 4       | laban  |
| 19 | 5       | laban  |
| 20 | 6       | pelle  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

topicId 1 was already read by userId "kalle" in id 1,7,8,14

topicId 2 was already read by userId "kalle" in id 4,5,6,11,12,15

And then I also would like to get the unique values in topicId, either id 13 or 17 can show up but not both.

I hope you understand what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM POST_TABLE WHERE ID IN
(
        SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM POST_TABLE WHERE TOPICID NOT IN
              (
                SELECT DISTINCT TOPICID  FROM POST_TABLE WHERE USERID ='kalle'
              )
        GROUP BY TOPICID
)
```

Comment: A human readable description of what this does and why it works would be helpful for future readers.